# Vigenere Cipher Python Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, padding, vigenere

How do you program this Vigenere cipher?

I am doing a problem where i encrypt and decrypt a Caesar and Vigenere cipher and am having a hard time coming up with it. I am not allowed to change any of the code. I can only add code under the definitions. I do have this on github.

https://github.com/michaelschmitt39/encryption

Some more information I am given:

About the Vigenere cipher:
The key used by the Vigenere cipher is a string. And more importantly, it must be a substring extracted from the plain text. Suppose the key is “Bob”, since the length of “Bob” is less than the plain text, you will need to pad the key to the same length of the plain text before the encryption:

The first letter, “A”, is encrypted by “B”. This means “B” has the index of 13 in the look-up list, such that “A” will then shift down 13 positions and becomes “b”. Another example is the second letter, “l”, is encrypted by “o”, which has an index of 7 based on the look-up list. Thus, “l” will be shifted down 7 positions and becomes “o” after the encryption. Implement the encrypt and decrypt methods for the Vigenere cipher. The encrypt method takes the plain text as input and generates its encrypted counterpart named cipher_text. The decrypt method decrypts the cipher_text and returns the plain text.

I am really having some issues with the Vigenere. When the code is showing up 
for the if - name- main, on this site it shows it incorrectly but assume that it is correct.The actual code should look like this -->   if__name__=="main":

I have tried multiple things. I know I have to pad the key and I believe that is my issue.

## The plain text

plain_text = "Talks between the United Auto Workers union and General Motors \"have taken a turn for the worse, according to the union's chief negotiator, suggesting that no immediate end is in sight for the auto industry's longest strike in decades. The setback in talks followed several days of reported progress between the two sides. They hope to reach a new four-year deal. Terry Dittes, the vice president of the United Auto Workers union negotiating team, sent a letter to members midday Sunday saying that the union found the company's latest contract proposal to be totally unacceptable to the union."

```
def look_up_list_gen(text):
    return list(text)  


class CaesarCipher:
    alphabet = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

    def __init__(self, key):
        assert(key > 0 and type(key) == int)
        self.key = key


    def encrypt(self, plain_text):
        cipher_text = look_up_list_gen(plain_text)
        encrypt_text = ''
        for letter in cipher_text:
            letter = letter.lower()
            if letter in self.alphabet:
                encrypt_text += self.alphabet[(self.alphabet.index(letter) + self.key) % 26 ]
            else:
                encrypt_text += letter
        self.cipher_text = encrypt_text




    def decrypt(self, plain_text):
        cipher_text = look_up_list_gen(plain_text)
        decrypt_text = ''

        for letter in cipher_text:
            if letter in self.alphabet:
                decrypt_text += self.alphabet[(self.alphabet.index(letter) - self.key) % 26 ]
            else:
                decrypt_text += letter

        return decrypt_text




class VigenereCipher:
    def __init__(self, key, look_up_list):
        assert(type(key) == str)
        self.key = key



    def encrypt(self, plain_text):
        assert(len(self.key) <= len(plain_text))



    def decrypt(self):
        assert(len(self.key) <= len(plain_text))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    caesar = CaesarCipher(3)
    caesar.encrypt(look_up_list_gen(plain_text))
    print("Encrypted text: ",caesar.cipher_text)
    print("""
                ---------------------------- 
    """)
    print("Decrypted text: ",caesar.decrypt(caesar.cipher_text).capitalize())

    vigenere = VigenereCipher(plain_text[:5],look_up_list_gen(plain_text))
    vigenere.encrypt(plain_text)
    print("Encrypted text: ",vigenere.cipher_text)
    print("Decrypted text: ",vigenere.decrypt())
```

Comment: You've provided a general proplem statement, what is your _specific_ question? What have you tried, and what was wrong with your attempt? Note the [guidance on asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on stack overflow, and be aware of your school's policies

Comment: I really dont know where to start.  I dont understand padding the key.

Comment: Is this question not public?